# A good 2d engine for Java?

Tags: java, graphics, 2d, sprite

Does anyone knows a good 2D engine for Java with sprites, animations and collisions handling?

Comment: What kind of games? Any in particular?

Comment: For a tactical rpg I'm working on: http://sourceforge.net/projects/fatal-assault/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JGame is probably what you're looking for.

You might also want to check out this question ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/293079/java-2d-game-frameworks ) that has a list of Engines out there and a bit of feedback on some of them. Hope it's helpful.

Comment: `Page Not Found` for your link.

Comment: Baffling why that question was removed, it was a good discussion, albeit 3 years old since thus answer was done. JGame, Slick2D, and LibGDX are still valid choices. Another URL to look at for choices: http://www.java-gaming.org/index.php?topic=26897.0

Answer (score 1):

[Slick2D](http://slick.cokeandcode.com/) seems to be a pretty solid choice.

It's widely used and it is based on OpenGL (via [LWJGL](http://www.lwjgl.org/)) so you can get some pretty good performance if you need it.

Answer (score 0):

[Greenfoot](http://www.greenfoot.org/door), from the makers of [BlueJ](http://bluej.org/), would be a good choice if it is your first time with game-development in Java. It is not even an easy-to-learn API, but also comes with a development-environment with fully integrated Greenfoot surface.

The game-environment is the [`greenfoot.World`](http://www.greenfoot.org/files/javadoc/greenfoot/World.html) while every element in the game is a [`greenfoot.Actor`](http://www.greenfoot.org/files/javadoc/greenfoot/Actor.html) instance. The Actor class provides a method for true bitmap-intersection ([`greeenfoot.Actor.intersects()`](http://www.greenfoot.org/files/javadoc/greenfoot/Actor.html#intersects%28greenfoot.Actor%29)).

Answer (score -1):

- jGame
- Arianne

Tangent: You'd be better off branching away from Java. The game development industry is C++/Python heavy, with C# in third.

Comment: Probably for denigrating Java; it actually makes a good game platform.

Comment: That's what I figured: fanboyism. If one reads carefully, you'll see I actually didn't denigrate Java. I just made true statement on what kind of languages are prevalent in the broader game industry. I didn't say you *can't* make a game in Java.

Comment: Yeah, but your entire answer had nothing to do with the OPs question. He just wanted to find a good Java engine, he didn't ask anything about the game industry as a whole.

Comment: @SoftwareMonkey: I did not "denigrate" Java. That's preposterous. I informed the OP that the industry is heavily biased to C++.

Comment: @vodnik: My entire answer did not. But half was directly in answer to his question. The rest is something your fanboism couldn't swallow: a helpful additional comment. Very sad.

Comment: To be honest, it appears your "answer" was put there specifically to hand out unsolicited advice. If you remove that, it's relatively a pretty weak effort. And the advice may be terribly wrong. If the OP has no interest in going into commercialized gamedev, and is only an "indy" or hobby dev, they're going to be much better off (more productive) staying in Java for probably most types of games.

Comment: @Perce: "Specifically". Wow, I guess I can't help people who try too see things beyond their intended purpose. I guess downvotes from "perfect minds" are unavoidable. So much for trying to be helpful...

Comment: I don't mean it was put there specifically to steer someone away from Java (I expect you're also a Java dev yourself). I'm saying it _appeared_ that way (there's no way for a 3rd party to know for sure...)